# Connect ssh to cisco switch with ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, cisco, cisco-ios

I want to connect a ansible virtual machine to a cisco switch. When I try the command `ssh myuser@192.168.xxx.xxx` from my ansible manager, the connection is successfull but when I try to run a playbook from this same ansible manager I've this error:
`ssh connection failed: Failed to authenticate public key: Socket error: disconnected`.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

My playbook task with the command `ansible-playbook -i inventaire.ini cisco.yml --user myuser --ask-pass`:

```
---
- name: show version
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - show version
  register: output

- name: print output
  debug:
    var: output.stdout_lines
```

My variables:

```
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_user=user-ansible
ansible_password=xxx
ansible_connection=network_cli
```

I've already try to create the ssh connection as [this example](https://networklessons.com/uncategorized/ssh-public-key-authentication-cisco-ios). But without result.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to avoid this error. I've updated my variables with my cisco user instead of my ansible user and now it's working :)